# When Posting data in ASP.NET MVC using ajax , Data is null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

When Debugging the MVCcontroller, all the properties of eventDetails are null, although from the client side the properties have values

Ajax Call

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/schedule",
            data: {
                EventDetailsId: 1,
                Location: scheduleData.location,
                EventName: scheduleData.title

            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error occured!!")
            }
        });
```

EventDetails    Class

```
    public class EventDetails
        {
            public int EventDetailsId{ get; set; }
            public string Location { get; set; }
            public string EventName { get; set; }
    }
```

Post Call

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Schedule(EventDetails eventDetails)
    {
        return Json(new { status = true });
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When your input is complex type,Then server expects to receive a json format and deserialize it to the object type defined,in this scenario you are gonna have to meet server expectation.
Change your javascript code as follows:

```
var arr = {
    'EventDetailsId': 1,
    'Location': scheduleData.location,
    'EventName': scheduleData.title

};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/schedule",
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error occured!!")
    }
});
```

Comment: I had it that way initially, it was null

Comment: are you sure schedule method is called? did you check it in debug mode? did you hit F12 in your browser to see any possible errors?

Comment: yes, there are no errors, when it hits the schedule method the parameter values are null.

Comment: i tested and it worked perfectly ! exact copy of your code !

Comment: @Curious-programmer Did you happen to miss the JSON.stringify() when you tried it yourself? That may be what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I added [FromBody] attribute and the values are not null.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Schedule( [FromBody]EventDetails eventDetails)
    {
        return Json(new { status = true });
    }
```